# More time cost when erasing last element from unordered_map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unordered-map

I found a very strange phenomenon, which is that when erasing the last element from `unordered_map`, it cost much more time so that my program seemed running endless there. My IDE: VS2010

In my program, the `unordered_map` is defined as follows:

```
unordered_map<void*, int> m_hashmap_pos;
```

Initially, its size is `N`, where `N = 35838` in my program. Iteratively, I erase one element from this `unordered_map` so it contains the last one stored, up to now the time of each erasing operation seemed constant, and the information about this `unordered_map` can be seen from the following figure [image]:

From the figure we can see the only left key and the input matches, i.e. `0x0000000004a30c40`.

However, if I continue erasing the last one from this `unordered_map`, the program seemed run endless. I clicked the "pause" button to see which function it's in, I found it's called `_Orphan_me()` in file `xutility`.

Please help me with why this happen and how to avoid it.

For your convenience, I wrote the following code to simulate. You may try it in your computer.

```
int main()
{
    int N = 36000;
    unordered_map<void*, int> hm;
    vector<int**> A(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        A[i] = new int*;
        hm[A[i]] = i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if (i == N-1)
        {
           cout << "Start removing last element from unordered_map: Now is ";
           system("time /t");
        }

        hm.erase(A[i]);

        if (i == N-1)
        {
           cout << "removing completed! Now is ";
           system("time /t");
        }
     }
     system("pause");
}
```

[image]

Comment: So are we to assume there is nothing wrong with your program?  I ask, since you didn't post it.  You only described what you're doing, and descriptions without code means very little.  Or better yet, post a complete, but small program that duplicates the issue.  It can't be that difficult *if* the problem is as obvious as you say it is (an unordered_map, fill it up with values, delete values).

Comment: Please, please, please, exply me whats the purpose of having a map form `int*` to `int` (The later should be `std::size_t` if you are doing what I think), and doing something like `map[new int*] = index`. Thats a very odd and inefficient way of implementing a memory pool, I think.